# How can i create scrollable data widget or chart in power BI Desktop?

Tags: animation, powerbi, dashboard, animated-gif

I want to create scrollable data widget or chart in power BI desktop like https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/80174214/193887395-f1c95042-b4e6-480e-a89c-a78aa247fa90.gif

If directly not possible then is there any way to embed gif or html to achieve my goal? which version (free / pro) is required to achieve my goal?

i did try to create or expecting like https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/80174214/193887395-f1c95042-b4e6-480e-a89c-a78aa247fa90.gif